# How to continuously stream data points from dynamically growing list using matplotlib.animation for real time graphing?

Tags: python, list, animation, matplotlib, data-modeling

I am wanting to plot a line from my data in real-time using matplotlib.animation module for python. The overview of my code is that I am calculating a score a storing it in a list("my_average") and this is the y-coordinate. The score will always be between -1 & +1. further more I would like my x-coordinate to be the length of my list "(len(my_average))".Ex; list recieves one score x-coordinate would the length of the list so 1 and y-coordinate would be the score, list receives second score, list plots (1, score1) (2, score2), etc.   I am not able to show the graph and need help with this portion of my code. Further more if possible I would not like to read the list from a csv file but rather directly from memory and still be able to view previous data points in history.

Here is the code:

```
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
import json
from textblob import TextBlob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import time
import numpy

# Variables that contains the user credentials to access Twitter API
access_token = 
access_token_secret = 
consumer_key = 
consumer_secret = 


# This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to stdout.
my_list = [] #creates empty list
my_average = []
class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        json_load = json.loads(data)
        texts = json_load['text'] # string
        #print(texts)
        wiki = TextBlob(texts)
        r = wiki.sentiment.polarity
        my_list.append(r)
        #drop zero in list
        if 0 in my_list: my_list.remove(0)  
        print (my_list)   

        #calculate average
        average = numpy.mean(my_list)
        b = my_average.append(average)
        #drop "nan" from list
        if 'nan' in my_average: my_average.remove('nan')
        print "average", my_average

        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 10), ylim=(0, -10))
        line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

        def init():
            line.set_data([], [])
            return line,

# animation function.  This is called sequentially
        def animate(i):
            x = (len(my_average))
            y = (my_average)
            line.set_data(x, y)
            return line,

            anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,frames=100, interval=20, blit=True)
            plt.show() 

            return True

        def on_error(self, status):
            print(status)

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
stream = Stream(auth, StdOutListener())

# This line filter Twitter Streams to capture data by the keywords: 'python', 'javascript', 'ruby'
stream.filter(track=['USD/CAD', 'Dollar', 'Loonie' ], languages=['en'])
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a twitter key to test your full code, however here is a code sample that you can adapt to animate a plot. A disadvantage of this approach is that you need to kill the process to stop the animation. This example plots the average along with the raw data, for illustration.

```
import numpy
from pylab import *
import time

class StdOutListener():
  def __init__(self):
    self.start_time = time.time()
    self.x = []
    self.y = []
    self.my_average = []
    self.line_actual, = plot(self.x, self.y)                  # line stores a Line2D we can update
    self.line_average, = plot(self.x, self.my_average)       # line stores a Line2D we can update


  def on_data(self, new_value):
    time_delta = time.time() - self.start_time                # on our x axis we store time since start
    self.x.append(time_delta)
    self.y.append(new_value)
    self.my_average.append(numpy.mean(self.y))
    self.line_actual.set_data(self.x, self.y)
    self.line_average.set_data(self.x, self.my_average)
    ylim([min(self.y), max(self.y)])        # update axes to fit the data
    xlim([min(self.x), max(self.x)])
    draw()                                  # redraw the plot

ion()                                       # ion() allows matplotlib to update animations.

out_listener = StdOutListener()
for i in range(1000):
  out_listener.on_data(i + numpy.random.randint(-5,5))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. 

I have implemented your code and I keep running into 

error "line 75, in <module>
    out_listener.on_data(i + random.randint(-5,5))
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'randint'"

I do not understand this error can you please advise?

Thank you very much

Comment: this looks like a namespace collision. Your 'random' module may not be the default python 'random' module. Try using `numpy.random.randint(-5,5)` instead. I've updated the code.

Comment: Wow! Hell ya it works beautifully! Thank you so much saving my butt!

Comment: If possible could you please explain what and why we have added this line in your code and what it does:

for i in range(1000):
   out_listener.on_data(i + numpy.random.randint(-5,5)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sure, i'm just simulating new data coming in, but with noise. If it were just on_data(i), you'd see a straight line. This way the line is jagged, closer to data you actually observe.

Comment: thank you for the quick response. Last question, the above class you have made, why do I need to make a new class for the animation?

Comment: You don't need to make a new class, I was just trying to mimic your example code, using a listener. I figured it would be easier for you to adapt to your code that way.

Comment: The graphic was not showing up. Adding a plt.pause(0.0000001) in the while helps the plot get fired :)